# How can i solve the error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception for removing duplicate images

Tags: magento-1.9, error, image, media, exception

I am try to delete duplicate images using this source [link](https://www.blueclaw.co.uk/blog/2013/09/12/removing-duplicate-product-images-in-magento/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to retrieve a file that does not exists:

```
file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\giri\media\catalog\product);
```

This is the line trigerring the exception.

Your custom code probably loops through images and tries to import an image that is not set or empty.

To solve it you need to modify the code from the link you posted and add some checks.

Replace:

```
$filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $base_image  ;
if(file_exists($filepath))
    $_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
```

With:

```
if ($base_image) {
    $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $base_image  ;
    if(file_exists($filepath))
        $_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
}
```

And replace:

```
        $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $_image->getFile()  ;
        if(file_exists($filepath))
            $md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
        else
            continue;

        if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
        {
            $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),  $_image->getFile());
            echo "rn removed duplicate image from ".$_product->getSku();
            $count++;
        } else {
            $_md5_values[] = $md5;
        }
```

With:

```
 if ($image->getFile()) {
        $filepath =  Mage::getBaseDir('media') .'/catalog/product' . $_image->getFile()  ;
        if(file_exists($filepath))
            $md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
        else
            continue;

        if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
        {
            $mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(),  $_image->getFile());
            echo "rn removed duplicate image from ".$_product->getSku();
            $count++;
        } else {
            $_md5_values[] = $md5;
        }
}
```

Comment: how can i solve this one

Comment: @JeevaRathinam see my update

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some file permission issues, probably on the dup.php file put possibly on the image files too, i'd recommend resetting file permissions then giving it another shot.

You can do this via the command line with the following:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: i am new to magento, could you pls explain briefly.

Comment: The error you have is saying permission denied when trying to access a file, the php script is probably fine but there is a common issue with the uploader that causes images to be uploaded with the wrong file permissions (Making them inaccessible)

If you run those commands it will update any files and folders that may have invalid permissions.

All you have to do is ssh into your local server, navigate to the root of magento and copy those commands into your terminal window.